Predictable Network Interface Names doesn't rename NFS root interface
With NFS root and Predictable Network Interface, I got differences in ethernet interface names: one interface configured by Kernel is named eth0, and others are named according to Network device naming schemes. So, when the same Image is booted locally and via network, the final names of the same interfaces are different. These appear to interfere with some configs, e.g. I got a ptp4l.service config that uses [eth0], so I must create separate configs with [end0] and [eth0] for local and network boot accordingly, that seems inconvenient.
When using NFS root, you have one ethernet interface on which NFS root relies on. So it's configured and named by Kernel, and can't be set down.
With NFS root systemd-udevd.service shows that it can't rename eth0:
systemd-udevd[180]: eth0: Network interface 'eth0' is already up, refusing to rename to 'end0'.

But eth0 already has ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD
# udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/eth0 2> /dev/null
ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v252
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD=end0

I'm not considering disabling Predictable Network Interface Names.
So, is there a way to set ethernet interface name during Kernel boot or force systemd-udevd to rename already configured interface with ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD?

Does a manual rename succeed? That is, if the interface cannot be set down, are you sure it can be renamed at all?

No, manual rename also fails, it says
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
And when I try to set down system hangs.
I thought, maybe Predictable Network Interface Names were tested with NFS root and there is the proper solution for this case. Because otherwise it's seems like a disadvantage of using PNIN

In that case how do you expect systemd-udevd to be able to rename it even if you "force" it to?

I expected PNIN to be able to rename it somehow. It may have been tested using NFS root and there is a working solution for renaming such interfaces.


or force systemd-udevd to rename already configured interface with ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD

You can do that easily, but you will then see that the kernel refuses to change the name and there is no point in trying to beat systemd-udevd into submission when it's not the one at fault.
There is no magic to "Predictable Network Interface Names"; it's just an udev rule, and udev uses the same method as ip link set does to rename an interface.

maybe Predictable Network Interface Names were tested with NFS root and there is the proper solution for this case

The usual solution recommended by systemd/udev is to start using an initramfs – instead of having the kernel configure the network before any processes start, an initramfs would do that in userspace (which then mounts the NFS root as well), and that means the initramfs could start systemd-udevd or do any other renaming before it proceeds with network configuration.
Recent versions of systemd-networkd even recognize the kernel cmdline network parameters so that it would be easier to include that in an initramfs.
